# single quote in contact form 7 input field throwing error on form submission

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Single quote in contact form 7 input field throwing error `There was an error trying to send your message. Please try again later.` on form submission.

How to allow Single and double quote in contact form 7 input(text) field (as these are the part of name)?

Comment: Part of the name attribute of the input? What do you mean part of the name?

Comment: I mean single quote comes in people name so it should be allowed in text field.